# Can a writeable stream be piped to either a readable or wirtable stream

Tags: node.js

*code:*

```
a.pipe(b).pipe(c).pipe(d);
```

Im node newbie. I read that for piping, the source should be a readable stream and destination should be a writeable stream.

1. If you see the above code, my assumption is that 'a' is readable
   stream, 'b' is writable stream. If 'b' is writable stream how is it
   possible to pipe it further?
2. how the 'b' writeable stream is piped to 'c'?
3. Streams and Buffers is being difficult to understand. Any good documentation to
   read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1: Yes, `a` must be a readable stream, and `b` must be a writable one. But, streams are not neccessarily *either / or*, they also can be both: Readable and writeable at the same time. So, `b` and `c` are both, hence you can pipe into them, but also pipe from them. Technically they are so-called [duplex streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_duplex).

Ad 2: Should be answered by now ;-).

Ad 3: Yes, you should definitely check out the [stream-handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) by [@substack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661591/substack) (aka James Halliday). For buffers, see [How to use buffers in Node.js](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers) by NodeJitsu.